# Как из массива сформировать строку вида

Tags: php, php7

Есть массив вида:

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [optgroup_id] => 1
        [type_id] => 1
        [type_title] => по Местности
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [optgroup_id] => 1
        [type_id] => 2
        [type_title] => по Обстановке
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [optgroup_id] => 1
        [type_id] => 3
        [type_title] => по Персонажу
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [optgroup_id] => 2
        [type_id] => 4
        [type_title] => по Цитате
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [optgroup_id] => 2
        [type_id] => 5
        [type_title] => по Силуэту
    )
```

)

Подскажите как его преобразовывать в строку вида:

"по Местности, по Обстановке, по Персонажу", "по Цитате, по Силуэту"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сгруппируйте по optgroup_id и потом в каждой группе сделайте строку из элементов type_title

```
function array_groupby($array, $fieldname) {

    $res = [];
    foreach ($array as $x) {
        if (is_array($x)) {
            $index = $x[$fieldname];
        }
        elseif (is_object($x)) {
            $index = $x->$fieldname;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception('array_groupby: illegal input array structure');
        }
        $res[$index][] = $x;
    }
    return $res;
}

function toString($sep, $col) {
    return function ($x) use ($sep, $col) {
        return implode($sep, array_column($x, $col)); };
}

$result = array_map(toString(', ', 'type_title'), array_groupby($arr, 'optgroup_id'));
print_r($result);    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item['optgroup_id']][]= $item['type_title'];
};

$put = '';
foreach ($result as $i) {
    $put .= '"' . implode(', ', $i) . '", '; 
}

rtrim($put, ', ');
```

Comment: что-то это не то

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @teran ¯\_(ツ)_/¯